# Saving initial payload using an expression exchange-property in groovy script in IFlow in CPI/HCI

Tags: groovy, apache-camel, save, payload, sap-pi

I am trying to save the first body in the payload in an exchange property and use it in the next block which is a groovy script. See my IFlow below:

[image]

Later, I am accessing this property as below:

```
String firstBody=message.getProperties().get("firstBody")
messageLog.addAttachmentAsString("Log", firstBody, "text/plain");
```

However, in the logs I get

> `org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@a0acbe1`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Sounds like your message body is stream based. See more at: http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching

Comment: There is also a Claim Check EIP that makes it easier to store / retrieve message body / data etc. See: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/claimCheck-eip.adoc

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the data type to `java.lang.String` in Content Modifier, Exchange Property.